# Spring Boot Application running on Tomcat can't access any resources

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I have a Java Spring Boot application that I am supposed to make some changes to. The application is currently running on our live servers with no issue.

When I deploy the app locally, I can see that it is there in my Tomcat /manager directory, but see the whitelabel error page with a 404 any time I try to access a resource. Is there a common cause for this issue? I can provide more details if necessary.

I've confirmed that the resources are present in the apache-tomcat-8.5.85/webapps/projectname/WEB-INF/ folder.

When attempting to access the resources I get only these debug lines in the console.

```
DEBUG 25796 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "FORWARD" dispatch for GET "/itsm-viewer/error", parameters={}
DEBUG 25796 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
DEBUG 25796 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8]
DEBUG 25796 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "FORWARD" dispatch, status 404
```

Comment: Without seeing your code and configuration it's not possible to give accurate answer